# Make x the subject given the formula for y

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am given the following formula:

$$y=\frac{x}{a}+\sqrt{\frac{x}{b}}.$$

I want to make x the subject.

I rearranged the equation and got to:

$$y^{4}=x(\frac{y^{2}}{2}+2y^{2})-x^{2}.$$

and I don't know where to go from here. May be this is the wrong rearrangement.

The answer according to wolfram alpha is:

$$x=\pm \frac{a^{\frac{3}{2}}\sqrt{a+4by}+a^{2}+2aby}{2b}.$$

How can I get there?

Comment: May you check if my answer below fits the above formula (from Wolfram alpha)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\textbf{a different approach}$

let $x = t^2$
thus your equation becomes
$$
y = \dfrac{t^2}{a} + \dfrac{t}{\sqrt{b}}
$$
solve for $t$ then compute $x$.

Comment: Did you mean $y = \dfrac{t^2}{a} + \dfrac{t}{\sqrt{b}}$?

Comment: Yes of course apologises. Thanks!

Comment: I found F using your answer and it is correct but for some reason the wolfram alpha answer is wrong.

Comment: My guess is you made some small mistake when you typed the question into Wolfram Alpha

Answer (score 8):

See $y$ as a quadratic function of $\sqrt {x}$. Use the quadratic formula.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Set $u=y^2$ and solve the quadratic equation for $u$.

Then your equation is rewritten as
$$
u^2=\frac{5x}{2}u-x^2,
$$

which by completing the square is written as

$$
\Bigg(u-\frac{5}{4}x\Bigg)^2 - \frac{9}{16}x^2=0,
$$

and thus you have

$$
u-\frac{5}{4}x = \pm\frac{3}{4}x,
$$

or

$$
u = \pm\frac{3}{4}x+\frac{5}{4}x = \frac{5\pm3}{4}x.
$$
Finally $y=\sqrt{u}=\sqrt{\frac{5\pm3}{4}x}$.

Comment: The goal of the problem is to solve for $x$ in terms of $a$, $b$, and $y$.

Comment: Sorry, I got the equation with fixed $a$, $b$, as it stated in the original post. I think it is trivial to follow the above procedure for the generic equation.

Comment: Actually, I cannot understand the reasons for the downvotes, but it's ok :)